# Coursera Course or book(s) That covers the following subjects: OPENSSL, SSH, PKI, MD5, RSA, Certificates, keys, signatures

Tags: rsa, reference-request, openssl, sha-1, ssh

I started working as a developper in a cryptography company 3 months ago where the applications are for mostly windows applications. I found that I don't have enough knowledge concerning the topics listed in the table that is  taken from [Hurdles for Developers in Cryptography.](https://export.arxiv.org/pdf/2108.07141)[image]

Indeed, these are the subjects that most developers find hard to grasp. Including me of course. I started looking for courses on Coursera. But I would like some help in picking the right course. I picked two interesting courses. Do you agree with the selection? are they a good starting point?

- [Basic Cryptography and Programming with Crypto API](https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-cryptography-and-crypto-api)
- [Windows Server Management and Security](https://www.coursera.org/learn/windows-server-management-security#syllabus)